Pyspark - Unable to display the DataFrame contents using df.show() on Windows 11
I have followed the official documentation to set up Apache Spark on my local Windows 11 machine.
This setup includes:

Proper installation of Apache Spark, setting up the env variables etc.
Creation of a virtual env specifically for Python 3.9 to ensure compatibility with PySpark.

Despite these steps, I'm encountering a ShowString error in VS Code:
While I can initiate a Spark session successfully and it starts without errors, I run into problems when trying to use df.show() to display DataFrame contents. The method fails and returns a ShowString error.
Not sure if the current version of java17 spark3.5 are supporting showstring on win11.
But any suggestions are highly appreciated :)
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/2fBDWU3M.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/3mjFNGlD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/gTm3ecIz.png)

I've tried multiple debug steps - verifying that the env variables are currently pointed and making sure that the spark sessions starts.

Was looking at the spark UI to debug this and realized that the SparkEnv was basically looking for a python3 executable file

creating an alias of python3.exe using python.exe and explicitly specifying in the python path helped.

import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Define the Python executable path or alias
python_path = r'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python3.exe'  
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = python_path
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = python_path

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Your App Name") \
    .config("spark.python.worker.exec", python_path) \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'Alice'), (2, 'Bob')], ['id', 'name'])
df.show()

+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|Alice|
|  2|  Bob|
+---+-----+

